# Beautiful Soup - Blank screen for a long time without any output

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am quite new to python and am working on a scraping based project- where I am supposed to extract all the contents from links containing a particular search term and place them in a csv file. As a first step, I wrote this code to extract all the links from a website based on a search term entered. I only get a blank screen as output and I am unable to find my mistake.

```
import urllib
import mechanize
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import datetime

def searchAP(searchterm):
    newlinks = []
    browser = mechanize.Browser()
    browser.set_handle_robots(False)
    browser.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Firefox')]
    text = ""
    start = 0

    while "There were no matches for your search" not in text:
        url = "http://www.marketing-interactive.com/"+"?s="+searchterm
        text = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(text, "lxml")
        results = soup.findAll('a')
        for r in results:
            if "rel=bookmark" in r['href'] :
                newlinks.append("http://www.marketing-interactive.com"+ str(r["href"]))  
        start +=10
                return newlinks  
       print searchAP("digital marketing")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following script extracts all the links from the web page based on given search key. But it does not explore beyond the first page. Although the following code can easily be modified to get all results from multiple pages by manipulating page-number in the URL (as described by *Rutger de Knijf* in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44968594/beautiful-soup-blank-screen-for-a-long-time-without-any-output/44976576#44976576).).

```
from pprint import pprint
import requests
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

def get_url_for_search_key(search_key):
    base_url = 'http://www.marketing-interactive.com/'
    response = requests.get(base_url + '?s=' + search_key)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)

    return [url['href'] for url in soup.findAll('a', {'rel': 'bookmark'})]
```

Usage:

```
pprint(get_url_for_search_key('digital marketing'))
```

Output:

```
[u'http://www.marketing-interactive.com/astro-launches-digital-marketing-arm-blaze-digital/',
 u'http://www.marketing-interactive.com/singapore-polytechnic-on-the-hunt-for-digital-marketing-agency/',
 u'http://www.marketing-interactive.com/how-to-get-your-bosses-on-board-your-digital-marketing-plan/',
 u'http://www.marketing-interactive.com/digital-marketing-institute-launches-brand-refresh/',
 u'http://www.marketing-interactive.com/entropia-highlights-the-7-original-sins-of-digital-marketing/',
 u'http://www.marketing-interactive.com/features/futurist-right-mindset-digital-marketing/',
 u'http://www.marketing-interactive.com/lenovo-brings-board-new-digital-marketing-head/',
 u'http://www.marketing-interactive.com/video/discussing-digital-marketing-indonesia-video/',
 u'http://www.marketing-interactive.com/ubs-melvin-kwek-joins-credit-suisse-as-apac-digital-marketing-lead/',
 u'http://www.marketing-interactive.com/linkedins-top-10-digital-marketing-predictions-2017/']
```

Hope this is what you wanted as the first step for your project.

Answer (score 1):

You made four mistakes:

1. You are defining `start` but you never use it. (Nor can you, as far as I can see on `http://www.marketing-interactive.com/?s=something`. There is no url based pagination.) So you endlessly looping over the first set of results.
2. `"There were no matches for your search"` is not the no-results string returned by that site. So it would go on forever anyway.
3. You are appending the link, including `http://www.marketing-interactive.com` to `http://www.marketing-interactive.com`. So you would end up with `http://www.marketing-interactive.comhttp://www.marketing-interactive.com/astro-launches-digital-marketing-arm-blaze-digital/`
4. Concerning `rel=bookmark` selection: [arifs solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44975069/1393879)  is the proper way to go. But if you really want to do it this way you'd need to something like this:

   ```
   for r in results:
       if r.attrs.get('rel') and r.attrs['rel'][0] == 'bookmark':
           newlinks.append(r["href"])
   ```

   This first checks if `rel` exists and then checks if its first child is `"bookmark"`, as `r['href']` simply does not contain the `rel`. That's not how BeautifulSoup structures things.

To scrape this specific site you can do two things:

1. You could do something with Selenium or something else that supports Javascript and press that `"Load more"` button. But this is quite a hassle.
2. You can use this loophole: `http://www.marketing-interactive.com/wp-content/themes/MI/library/inc/loop_handler.php?pageNumber=1&postType=search&searchValue=digital+marketing`
   This is the url that feeds the list. It has pagination, so you can easily loop over all results.

Comment: I had corrected the mistakes as you had pointed out and used your snippet -                                                                                     
    for r in results:
    if r.attrs.get('rel') and r.attrs['rel'][0] == 'bookmark':
        newlinks.append(r["href"])                                                                             and still got "Press any key to continue" as the output. Even arif's bookmark solution in my code gave the same output

Comment: I have used selenium(as suggested by you) to access the load more button. I do have issues scraping newly loaded links. Could u please have a look? [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45452281/beautiful-soup-article-url-scraping-unable-to-scrape-urls-of-additionally-loa]