# Beautiful Soup - Article URL scraping. Unable to scrape URLs of additionally loaded articles

Tags: python, function, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am writing a program to scrape URLs of articles from a website based on a search term. Currently I am able to only scrape article URLs from the first page.

I am able to access the load button and load additional articles but I am unable to scrape their URLs.

I have split the entire code into 2 separate modules for better clarity. I tried to combine them into a single module but the output was-just the article URLs of the first page repeatedly being displayed. I need help in combining these 2 modules into a single working module.

#### This code scrapes article URL's from the first page based on a search term

```
from pprint import pprint
import requests
import lxml
import csv
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

####Function returns list of URLs based on search key#####

def get_url_for_search_key(search_key):
    base_url = 'http://www.marketing-interactive.com/'
    response = requests.get(base_url + '?s=' + search_key)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")
    newlinks = []
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
    results = soup.findAll('a', {'rel': 'bookmark'})
    return [url['href'] for url in soup.findAll('a', {'rel': 'bookmark'})] 
pprint(get_url_for_search_key('digital marketing'))


### Scraped Links written into csv file(under a single column) ###

with open('ctp_output.csv', 'w+') as f:

    f.seek(0)
    f.write('\n'.join(get_url_for_search_key('digital marketing')))

### Scraped Links read from csv file and respective information is scraped and written into text file ###

with open('ctp_output.csv', 'rb') as f1:
    f1.seek(0)
    reader = csv.reader(f1)

    for line in reader:
        url = line[0]       
        soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url), "lxml")

        with open('ctp_output.txt', 'a+') as f2:
            for tag in soup.find_all('p'):
                f2.write(tag.text.encode('utf-8') + '\n')
```

#### This code automatically accesses the "LOAD MORE" button and loads the rest of the articles

```
from retry import retry
from explicit import waiter
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException

@retry(StaleElementReferenceException, tries=10, delay=0.5)
def click_more(driver):
    waiter.find_element(driver, 'div.loadm').click()

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

try:
    driver.get("http://www.marketing-interactive.com/?s=digital+marketing")

    while True:
        click_more(driver)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no need for clicking "load more", cause when you click on the "load more" it sends a ajax request like this

"http://www.marketing-interactive.com/wp-content/themes/MI/library/inc/loop_handler.php?pageNumber=2&postType=search&searchValue=facebook"

Here you just change the pageNumber and get new list of data.If there is no article available it will send you a blank response

"http://www.marketing-interactive.com/wp-content/themes/MI/library/inc/loop_handler.php?pageNumber=1000&postType=search&searchValue=facebook"

Comment: `def get_url_for_search_key():
    for i in range(1,100):
        base_url = 'http://www.marketing-interactive.com/'
    response = requests.get(base_url + '/wp-content/themes/MI/library/inc/loop_handler.php?pageNumber=%s&postType=search&searchValue='search_key)%i
    `                                Tried this but got a typeerror with respect to %i

Comment: **unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'Response' and 'int'  **- this is the error i get. I removed the search_key parameter in the definition and declaration and entered the actual search term in the url statement.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/JT3mEjAP take a look of this code, but after use this code you will must read this link https://pyformat.info/

Comment: Thanks for that useful link. I tried your snippet. When I use print(response.status_code) and call `get_url_for_search_key()`  I get 200 printed repeatedly.

Comment: use response.text, 200 is the response code. now read about requests module, http request response, http status code etc.

Comment: Still doesn't work. I get a blank screen in the output window :(